# Bash conditional 'OR' of grep results

Tags: bash, if-statement, grep, stdout

I am trying to do a conditional check of the result of two grep commands in a bash script, but I cannot seem to combine them like:

```
if [[ $( stout_cmd1 | grep -q 'check_txt1' ) || ( $( stdout_cmd2 | grep -q 'check_txt2' ) ]] ; then
    //do something here if output of stdout_cmdX contains text check_txtX
fi
```

as it always returns false. Conditionally checking the commands on their own work as intended:

```
if stdout_cmd1 | grep -q 'check_txt1' ; then
```

or

```
if stdout_cmd2 | grep -q 'check_txt2' ; then
```

I don't know how to check if either one is true. How does one combine two stdout outputs in a conditional check? I have removed the `-q` flag from the grep calls with no effect.

Comment: Try this one: `if { stout_cmd1 | grep -q 'check_txt1' } || { stdout_cmd2 | grep -q 'check_txt2' }; then`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Actually* you just use the `exit-code` of `grep` directly after asking it to run silent `-q`

```
if cmd1 | grep -q "check_txt1" || cmd2 | grep -q "check_txt2"
then
    echo "Your code here!"
fi
```

Comment: Process substitution provides no benefit in this case, and only serves to make your script less portable to other shells.

Comment: @TobySpeight: Avoids forking a pipe-line! and with all due respect why do you think it is less portable? I don't think it's harmful as long as OP has tagged it with `bash`

Comment: Why do you think that process substitution has less fork than ordinary pipelining?  AFAICS, the same number of processes need to be created.  And I prefer portable answers generally (or at least pointing out what's not portable), because they are of more help to readers other than the poster of the Question.

Comment: @TobySpeight: If any part of my answer is incorrect, I'd be more than happy to modify but simply I don't see a modification to the answer when used in the context of `bash`

Comment: agree with idea of @TobySpeight about portability (only work on "linux" world where few change make it works on old unix also), and fork occurence, both use same forking process count. It could be interesting to make a perf test on it to show if there is a real difference between pipe and input redirection. Now on, your reply IS a good one, and helpfull

Comment: @Inian A process substitution forks just as much as a pipeline. Their use in something like `while read; do ...; done < <(cmd)` vs `cmd | while read; do ...; done` is to prevent the `while` loop, which could otherwise execute directly in the current shell (which might set some shell variables to use later) instead of running in a subshell.

Comment: @chepner: Thanks for that, makes sense now! Edited the answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

The `[[` compound command evaluates a *conditional expression*, but you just want the result of a pipeline.  You need to combine your two pipelines in a *list* using `||`:

```
if stout_cmd1 | grep -q 'check_txt1' || stdout_cmd2 | grep -q 'check_txt2'
then
    # your code here
fi
```

From the Bash manual:

> A **list** is a sequence of one or more pipelines separated by one of the operators `;`, `&`, `&&`, or `||`, and optionally terminated by one of `;`, `&`, or *`<newline>`*.
>   ...
>   The return status of AND and OR lists is the exit status of the last command executed in the list.

## Demonstration

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in 00 01 02 12
do
    if echo "$i" | grep -q '1' || echo "$i" | grep -q '2'
    then
        echo "$i contains a 1 or 2"
    else
        echo "$i contains neither 1 nor 2"
    fi
done
```

This produces the following output:

```
00 contains neither 1 nor 2
01 contains a 1 or 2
02 contains a 1 or 2
12 contains a 1 or 2
```